# Fit big GAM with constraints on linear terms

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, constrained-regression

I'm trying to fit MGCV GAM with constraints on linear terms. I feed a dataset with factor variable `G`. Number of rows is about 30-40k. Number of model parameters - 100-200. This means I have to use `bam` for initial estimate.

```
mf <- Y ~ 0 + G + X1:G + s(X2, bs = "cc", k = 12) # model form

# fit big gam
cl <- makeCluster(4) 
mbam <- bam(mf, family=poisson, data=dataset, cluster=cl)
stopCluster(cl)

coefs <- coef(mbam)
NG <- nlevels(dataset$G)
NC <- length(coefs)

mgam <- gam(mf, family=poisson, data=dataset, fit=FALSE)

# inequality constraints: all X1:G coefficients must be > 0
mgam$Ain <- cbind(matrix(0, NG, NG),
                  diag(NG),
                  matrix(0, NG, NC - 2 * NG))
mgam$bin <- rep(0, NG)
mgam$sp <- mbam$sp
mgam$p <- coefs
mgam$p[NG:(NG * 2)] <- 1 # make initial parameters values satisfy constraints
mgam$C <- matrix(0, 0, 0)

pcls_out <- pcls(mgam)
```

In this code `pcls` fails with `Error in pcls(mgam) : QPCLS - Rank deficiency in model`. I tried to feed it with different non-sparse datasets, and ordinary GAM successfully fits them. Probably the problem is not in data? Am I using `pcls` in proper way?